# How to hide a "No categories" using this code?

Tags: wordpress, categories

So I have this code, works perfect, but when I go to the last category it displays **"No categories"** if there is a way to hide this last display?

thanks

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $cur_cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
    if ( $cur_cat ) {
        $new_cats = wp_list_categories( 'echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat . '&depth=1&title_li=&&hide_empty=1' );
        echo '<ul>' . $new_cats . '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress `wp_list_categories()` function returns "No categories" when there is an empty result for the arguments provided.

So, the last category won't have any child categories or it's not been assigned to a post yet.

You can change the text by adding the `show_option_none` argument as mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).